# Update one dropdown from another dropdown on a bound web form in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have an edit form that is bound to existing data.  I have two dropdowns that I would like have update each up depending on specific criteria.  For example, is  I set the assignedTo to blank, change the status to UnAssigned, and/or if I change the status to UnAssigned, change the AssignedTo to be blank, etc.

Status Dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control edit-status" id="status" name="status">
        <option selected="{{equals status 'UnAssigned'}}" value="UnAssigned">UnAssigned</option>
        <option selected="{{equals status 'Open w Vendor'}}" value="Open w Vendor">Ticket with Vendor</option>
        <option selected="{{equals status 'Not Started'}}" value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
        <option selected="{{equals status 'In Progress'}}" value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
        <option selected="{{equals status 'Reopened'}}" value="Reopened">Reopened</option>
      </select>
```

Assigned To Dropdown

```
<select class="form-control edit-assigned-to" id="assignedTo" name="assignedTo">
        <option value="" selected="{{equals assignedTo ''}}">Select a User</option>
        {{#each users}}
          <option value="{{_id}}" selected="{{equals ../assignedTo _id}}">{{services.auth0.name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
```

I already have an equality helper on each of them to pick the value that is already set when loading the form data.  I was thinking of using Reactive Vars with change events, but I'm unsure how to exactly to implement that or if I'm even on the right track.  T

Comment: Where are `status` and `assignedTo` stored? Are these inside a collection? Your case is so simple you probably don't even need a reactive var if you can touch the value of those two variables directly.

Comment: They are in a collection.  I'm not sure I follow though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using some jquery in my change events.

```
'change .edit-status': function(event, template){
  var status = event.target.value;
  if (status === "UnAssigned") {
    $(".edit-assigned-to").val("");
  }
  return false;
},

'change .edit-assigned-to': function(event, template){
  var assignedTo = event.target.value;
  if (!template.data.assignedTo && assignedTo !== "") {
    $(".edit-status").val("Not Started");
  }
  if (assignedTo === "") {
    $(".edit-status").val("UnAssigned");
  }    
  return false;
}
```

I'm not sure if there are better approaches or pitfalls to this solution, but it seems to be meeting my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the collection that contains the `status` and `assignedTo` fields is called `myCollection`:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'change #status': function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var newStatus = $('#status).val();
    if ( newStatus == "UnAssigned" ){ // unset the assignedTo value
      myCollection.update({ _id: this._id },
        { $set: { status: newStatus}, $unset: { assignedTo: true }});
    } else {
      myCollection.update{ _id: this._id },{ $set: { status: newStatus}});
    }
  },
  'change #assignedTo': function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var newAssignedTo = $('#assignedTo').val();
    if ( newAssignedTo != "None" ){
      var userId = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: newAssignedTo });
      myCollection.update({ _id: this._id },{ $set: { assignedTo: newAssignedTo }});
    } else { // unset the assignedTo
    myCollection.update({ _id: this._id },
      { $set: { status: "UnAssigned" }, $unset { assignedTo: true }});
    }
  }
});
```

Note that in your template you're missing a way to select `"None"` as a value for the assigned user.

Comment: I get what you are saying now.  I actually want to change the dropdown values on the front end.  Let the user see the impact and then choose the submit the form or not.  So if remove a user from the AssignedTo dropdown, they see the Status dropdown change to UnAssigned for example.  Then on submit the fields get updated.  Sorry if I wasn't very clear and thanks for the taking the time to respond!